# Undefined index error after submitting form

Tags: php, html, forms

hi Please help me on this.. i hv created a form & trying to post data to mysql database. but after submitting form i am getting following error..

Notice: Undefined index: month in C:\xampp\htdocs\auto\insert_ac.php on line 14
Notice: Undefined index: listner_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\auto\insert_ac.php on line 15
Notice: Undefined index: rj_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\auto\insert_ac.php on line 16
Notice: Undefined index: channel in C:\xampp\htdocs\auto\insert_ac.php on line 17
Notice: Undefined index: year in C:\xampp\htdocs\auto\insert_ac.php on line 18
Notice: Undefined index: country in C:\xampp\htdocs\auto\insert_ac.php on line 19

& when i check a blank row entry inserted in to my database

```
  <?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username`
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name="auto"; // Database name
$tbl_name="song_request"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Get values from form
$month=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['month']);
$listner_name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['listner_name']);
$rj_name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['rj_name']);
$channel=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['channel']);
$year=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['year']);
$country=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country']);

// Insert data into mysql

$sql="INSERT INTO song_request (month, listner_name, rj_name, channel, year, country)VALUES('$month', '$listner_name', '$rj_name', '$channel', '$year', '$country')";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die ('error Updating database');

// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful".
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='index.html'>Back to main page</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}

// close connection
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: $_POST['month'] does not exist. Check your HTML form and ensure that a form element with a name of "month" exists there.

Comment: Variables listner_name,  rj_name, channel, year and country do not exist in the $_POST so there are two possible reasons: a) you do not have those fields in the form (or that they are spelled differently in the HTML and in the PHP), b) you are doing a GET submit (in the <form> tag you specified method="get" or you didn't specify method at all) which means that the $_GET collection is where you will find the missing fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your form looks like, but basically PHP tells you there is no `$_POST['month']`. What you really should do is start debugging. See what is in `$_POST` and what is not. Try to find out why PHP is telling you that `$_POST['month']` is non-existing.

Answer (score 0):

You have no month field on the form that's why you get that error.

`$_POST['month']` should be assigned when submitting the form, try to add that field to the form and try again.

Additionally you could check if it's set with [isset()](http://php.net/isset) and [empty()](http://php.net/empty) functions.